# Decode JSON in flask

Tags: python, json, flask

i want to send JSON format data in my flask app using AJAX call,
when i send it i got "None" in flask.

here is jquery,

```
$('#form').on('click',function(){
  var text = $('#textField').val();
  var obj = {name:text};
  var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
  $.ajax({
    data : myJSON,
    url: '/process',
    type : 'post',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType : 'json'
  })
})
```

here is my Flask route,

```
@app.route('/process',methods=["POST"])
def process():
    data = request.json
    return render_template("form.html",data = data)
```

in data i got "None".

Answer (score 1):

- `return render_template` is not fruitful as data is being sent via Ajax. It will return the template contents.
- You can receive the data returned from Flask via `done` method in Ajax.

I am adding an example code to demonstrate how to handle Ajax submission with JSON data.

`app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/process',methods=["GET", "POST"])
def process():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.json
        return jsonify(data)
    return render_template("form.html")

app.run(debug=True)
```

`form.html`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Form</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="data"></div>

        <input type="text" id="textField" />
        <button id="demo_btn">Dummy button</button>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#demo_btn").on("click", function() {
                    var text = $('#textField').val();
                    var obj = {name:text};
                    var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
                    $.ajax({                        
                        url: '/process',
                        type : 'post',
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        dataType : 'json',
                        data : myJSON
                    }).done(function(result) {
                        $("#data").html(result["name"]);
                    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log("fail: ",textStatus, errorThrown);
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>       
    </body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

[image: flask ajax json submission]

**Reference:**

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: after getting data i want to query it in database in SQLalchemy,  and  passing querying in render_template but using request.json i got "None" in data.

Comment: @HamzaAwan, have you tried my example? The `textField` form data is being sent to Flask in `data = request.json`. After getting this data you can make database query and return result to Ajax again. Hope it helps. :)

Comment: i have tried, it works, but i want to send data through render_template any idea how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like JQuery isn't setting the correct header.

If you use the `request.get_json()` method instead of the `request.json` property it will get json irrespective of the header.

Comment: i also used request.get_json() but  same result "None",
and i used request.get_json(force = True), i got this error,
Bad Request Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)