# Send JSON data to Flask server using JQuery .load()

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, json, flask

I am trying to use JQuery's `.load()` function to send data to my Flask server and, using that, render a `<div>` that is loaded into the calling element. My call looks something like this:

```
$("#element").load(
  "/get_data",
  {"info": info} // this is the problem
)
```

However, when I try to access this data in my Flask backend, the data is of form byte-string. (Accessing with `request.get_data()` yields a byte-string and `request.get_json()` yields `None`).

This did not surprise me, as the same behavior occurs when I use `.ajax()` requests. With Ajax, I simply use `data: JSON.stringify({"info":info})` and that sends a string easily read by `json.loads` to the Flask backend just fine. What befuddles me is when I attempt the same data packaging with `.load()`, the request to the server is a `GET` instead of a `POST`.

Per `.load()`'s [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/load/), "The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed." I don't understand why the data being a JSON string alters the behavior of `.load()` this way.

I'm keen to understand this behavior, but **my question** is how can I send data using JQuery's `.load()` to a Flask backend as a POST request in form JSON, or at least readable as a json (e.g. JSON string)?

Comment: are you using the right Content-Type header (application/json)?

Comment: This post may provide the solution you need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53502324/decode-json-in-flask

Comment: @AndreaPollini how would I assert the content-type for the incoming request? You can't do so via .load() and I'm unclear how you'd do that on the backend.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work.  You have data as `{"info": info}`, which is an object that `.load` should send as a POST.  Make sure you are getting a JSON mimetype object from the server.  Also, make sure your Flask view accepts the `POST` method:

```
from flask import Flask, request, Response
import json

@app.route('/get_data', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def get_data():
    payload_dict = json.loads(request.data.decode('utf-8'))
    # or try payload_dict = request.json
    print(payload_dict["info"])
    return Response(json.dumps({"info_response": "hello"}), mimetype='application/json')
```

And make sure you have `info` defined in `{"info": info}`

Thought about using getJSON: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ ?

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. That will send JSON data from the server to the front-end. I'm looking to send data from the frontend to the Flask server.

Comment: Your code should do that.  Unless `info` is not defined.  Should it be `{info: "info"}`? Also, does your view accept `POST` method?

Comment: No info is just filler, but the actual content in my code does exist. I think the miscue is that .load sends a JSON string as a GET request, but I can't figure out how to get Flask to handle a JSON Object

Comment: Thank you for your help; unfortunately nothing has worked. I settled on simply parsing the bytestring, which isn't ideal but it's still functional.

Comment: Did you use the `.decode('utf-8')` part in my answer?

Comment: Yes, I did decode the string using .decode("utf-8"), but you can't then load that into a json b/c it's of form "info=info".

Comment: That sounds like it's being sent as a GET, in the query string. Somewhere in your code `{info: info}` is a string.  Can you `console.log()` it before sending to make sure?